# Program gives unstable output?

Tags: c, windows, dev-c++

This is a cashier program. Please see the screenshot first.

---

the loop is where i think the problem comes from. more likely from lines with 'j' and 'k'.user enter item code(i), example, 2, search price[2]=2.49 according to textfile, save the price into another array ipprice[j],if this is the first item code entered, ipprice[0], so later i can print the first item purchased is ipprice[0], second and so on, those ipprice[j] are expected to remain unchanged, but it didn't, check the screenshot. system cls make the code looks messy, repeat printing is basically just trying keep some content on screen while clearing unwanted parts. k is used because j is involved in constant j++, increment for each item code entered, so the program knows this is the first item purchased, second so on.

**Full code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int main()
{
    int i,j=0,code,amt, key,lines=0;
    int id[i],stock[i],k=0;
    char name[i][20],product[100];
    float price[i],sum;
    float total=0;
    char ipname[j][20],ch;
    int quantity[j];
    float ipprice[j];
    float ipsub[j];

    FILE*fp1;

    fp1=fopen("Fruit.txt","r");
    if(fp1==NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR in opening file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        while((ch=getc(fp1))!=EOF)
        {
            if(ch=='\n')
                lines++;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp1);

    fp1=fopen("Fruit.txt","r");
    if(fp1==NULL){
        printf("ERROR in opening file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {

        for(i=0;i<lines;i++){
            fgets(product,sizeof(product),fp1);
            id[i]=atoi(strtok(product,","));
            strcpy(name[i],strtok(NULL,","));
            price[i]=atof(strtok(NULL,","));
            stock[i]=atoi(strtok(NULL,"\n"));

        }
    }
    fclose(fp1);

    printf("=============================================================\n");
    for(i=0;i<lines;i++)
    {
        printf("%d:%-10s\t",i+1,name[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n%-5s%-20s%-15s%-10s%s\n","No.","Product","Price","Quantity","Subtotal");
    printf("%-5s%-20s%-15s%-10s%s\n","===","=======","=====","========","========");

    do{
        k=0;
        if(j>0)
        {
            system("cls");
        }
        if(j>0)
        {
            printf("=============================================================\n");
            for(i=0;i<lines;i++)
            {
                printf("%d:%-10s\t",i+1,name[i]);
            }
            printf("\n\n%-5s%-20s%-15s%-10s%s\n","No.","Product","Price","Quantity","Subtotal");
            printf("%-5s%-20s%-15s%-10s%s\n","===","=======","=====","========","========");
            for(k=0;k<j;k++)
            {
                printf("%-5d%-20s%-15.2f%-10d%.2f\n",
                       k+1,ipname[k],ipprice[k],quantity[k],ipsub[k]);
            }
        }
        sum=0;
        amt=0;
        printf("\nProduct code:");
        scanf("%d",&code);
        i=code-1;
        printf("Quantity:");
        scanf("%d",&amt);
        system("cls");
        sum=price[i]*amt;
        total=total+sum;
        ipprice[j]=price[i];
        strcpy(ipname[j],name[i]);
        quantity[j]=amt;
        ipsub[j]=sum;
        printf("=============================================================\n");
        for(i=0;i<lines;i++){
            printf("%d:%-10s\t",i+1,name[i]);
        }
        printf("\n\n%-5s%-20s%-15s%-10s%s\n","No."
               ,"Product","Price","Quantity","Subtotal");
        printf("%-5s%-20s%-15s%-10s%s\n","===","=======","=====","========","========");
        for(k=0;k<=j;k++)
        {
            printf("%-5d%-20s%-15.2f%-10d%.2f\n",
                   k+1,ipname[k],ipprice[k],quantity[k],ipsub[k]);
        }
        printf("%d",j);
        printf("\nPress ESC on keyboard to finalize the bill or Press any key continue...\n");
        key=_getch();
        if(key!=27)
        {
            j++;
        }
    }while(key!=27);
    printf("%.2f",total);

    return 0;
}
```

**Textfile content**

```
18156,Apple,1.49,73
45776,Aprikot,1.59,23
73191,Avocado,2.49,63
72829,Banana,2.99,27
74084,Blueberry,5.49,36
79800,Coconut,3.49,80
16611,Grape,8.99,42
62690,Grapefruit,2.19,34
47089,Guava,4.99,42
70412,Jackfruit,19.99,29
44640,Kiwifruit,2.15,38
94768,Lemon,0.99,42
86240,Mango,3.99,62
78697,Orange,1.69,23
74470,Papaya,4.49,23
23959,Pear,2.49,36
78862,Pineapple,2.99,71
82943,Pomegranate,4.35,19
56180,Pomelo,12.99,72
67712,Starfruit,2.79,59
33974,Strawberry,13.99,31
12354,dildo,29.99,4
45584,Watermelon,6.88,21
```

[image: Screenshot of error]

**The loops**

```
do{
    k=0;
    if(j>0)//because this is only necessary if it is second loop
    {
        system("cls");
    }
    if(j>0)//same reason, j is later used to display and save item purchased
    {
        printf("=============================================================\n");
        for(i=0;i<lines;i++)
        {
            printf("%d:%-10s\t",i+1,name[i]);
        }
        printf("\n\n%-5s%-20s%-15s%-10s%s\n","No.","Product","Price","Quantity","Subtotal");
        printf("%-5s%-20s%-15s%-10s%s\n","===","=======","=====","========","========");
        for(k=0;k<j;k++)//i am trying to keep these content on screen while system cls
        {
            printf("%-5d%-20s%-15.2f%-10d%.2f\n",
                   k+1,ipname[k],ipprice[k],quantity[k],ipsub[k]);
        }
    }
    sum=0;
    amt=0;
    printf("\nProduct code:");
    scanf("%d",&code);
    i=code-1;
    printf("Quantity:");
    scanf("%d",&amt);//amt amount
    system("cls");
    sum=price[i]*amt;
    total=total+sum;
    ipprice[j]=price[i];  //ip is itempurchased
    strcpy(ipname[j],name[i]);
    quantity[j]=amt;
    ipsub[j]=sum;//subtotal
    printf("=============================================================\n");
    for(i=0;i<lines;i++){
        printf("%d:%-10s\t",i+1,name[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n%-5s%-20s%-15s%-10s%s\n",
           "No.","Product","Price","Quantity","Subtotal");
    printf("%-5s%-20s%-15s%-10s%s\n","===","=======","=====","========","========");
    for(k=0;k<=j;k++)
    {
        printf("%-5d%-20s%-15.2f%-10d%.2f\n",
               k+1,ipname[k],ipprice[k],quantity[k],ipsub[k]);
    }
    printf("\nPress ESC on keyboard to finalize the bill or Press any key continue...\n");
    key=_getch();
    if(key!=27)
    {
        j++;
    }
} while(key!=27);
```

Comment: Your code opens with `int i, ...;` then `int id[i],stock[i],k=0;` What do you think `i` is in that dimension declaration of `id` and `stock`? I.e. the first two lines invoke *undefined behavior*. The problem is replicated throughout the declarations of `main()`: Ex: `char name[i][20]`, `float price[i]`, etc. Likewise with `j` as a size index (which at least is initialized as `0`, not that it helps at all). I stopped reading after that.

Comment: @WhozCraig Hi, thankyou for anwering, can you give me an example of the right way? i is used to store product information from the text file , if the textfile has 23 lines, then the max i is 22, i maybe not clear about array, can you show me the right way?

Comment: Narrow the problem down a bit.

Comment: @problematic Honestly, not really. The purpose of this code is unclear, and I can easily see this turning into an online-debug-session, which is *not* constructive to this forum. The moment your arrays are "fixed", the likelihood of runtime-issues popping up is high. Any reasonable text on the C programming language in the last 15 years will have an entire chapter on array declaration and management. I suggest you start there.

Comment: Minor: Suggest `int ch; ... (ch=getc(fp1))!=EOF` instead of `char ch;`.  `getc()` typically returns 256 `unsigned char` values and `EOF`.  `EOF` will collide with one of the `char` values.

Comment: @EdHeal i don't know where the problem comes from, in the third box of code there is the part of loop where i think the problem comes from, i will try again to see if i can find out where exactly is the cause...

Comment: @problematic - use a debugger

Comment: @chux Hi, thank you for answering, please bare with my lack of skill to understand, that line of code is intended to determine the number of lines in the txt file, i googled it i don't really understand how it works,when there is new line then there is "\n" , so +1 when it finds "\n"?while != EOF so that it searches until it is over? can you show me the right way?

Comment: @EdHeal there is no error, it just give wrong output

Comment: "Textfile content" has 23 lines of data.  Command shell picture indicates 22.

Comment: @problematic  Not core this the post's problem, but recommend to use `int ch;` rather than `char ch;`.

Comment: Suspect `scanf("%d",&amt); ... key=_getch();` as `_getch()` is likley taking in the `'\n'` left-over from `scanf("%d",&amt);`.  Bad vibes to mix `scanf()` and `getc()`.  Suggest replacing `key=_getch();` with `scanf(" %c", &key);`.  Even better alternatives exist.

Comment: @WhozCraig Wow , i didn't understand what did u tell me but i know you are talking about array declaration, i changed all [i] and [j] in declaration to [100] and i think it works fine now, thank you very much!!

Comment: @chux I tried ur suggestions, i changed char to int and i think it is better now, but i can't change key=_getch() to scanf(" %c", &key), turns out i can't simply press enter to continue,  i press enter and it keeps asking for input.Thanks for helping me!!!

Comment: You need to compile with all warnings and debug info, and to **use the debugger** (a necessary skill).

Comment: I have more questions please help, how do i make use of self defined function in this code???

Comment: @chux hey chux do you know how can i use self defined function in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New code that works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int main()
{
int i,j=0,code,amt, key,lines=0;
int id[100],stock[100],k=0;
char name[100][20],product[100];
float price[100],sum;
float total=0;  
char ipname[100][20];
int quantity[100], ch;
float ipprice[100];
float ipsub[100];

FILE*fp1;

fp1=fopen("Fruit.txt","r");
if(fp1==NULL)
{
    printf("ERROR in opening file\n");
    return 1;
}
else
{
while((ch=getc(fp1))!=EOF)
    {
        if(ch=='\n')
        lines++;
    }
}
    fclose(fp1);

fp1=fopen("Fruit.txt","r");
if(fp1==NULL){
               printf("ERROR in opening file\n");
               return 1;
               }
               else
               {

               for(i=0;i<lines;i++){
                                    fgets(product,sizeof(product),fp1);
                              id[i]=atoi(strtok(product,","));
                             strcpy(name[i],strtok(NULL,","));
                             price[i]=atof(strtok(NULL,","));
                             stock[i]=atoi(strtok(NULL,"\n"));

                         }
                                }
                                    fclose(fp1);

printf("=============================================================\n");
for(i=0;i<lines;i++)
{
printf("%d:%-10s\t",i+1,name[i]);
}
printf("\n\n%-5s%-20s%-15s%-10s%s\n","No.","Product","Price","Quantity","Subtotal");
printf("%-5s%-20s%-15s%-10s%s\n","===","=======","=====","========","========");

do{  
k=0;
if(j>0)
{
system("cls");
}
if(j>0)
{
    printf("=============================================================\n");
    for(i=0;i<lines;i++)
{
printf("%d:%-10s\t",i+1,name[i]);
}
printf("\n\n%-5s%-20s%-15s%-10s%s\n","No.","Product","Price","Quantity","Subtotal");
printf("%-5s%-20s%-15s%-10s%s\n","===","=======","=====","========","========");
    for(k=0;k<j;k++)
    {
printf("%-5d%-20s%-15.2f%-10d%.2f\n",k+1,
ipname[k],ipprice[k],quantity[k],ipsub[k]);
    }
}
sum=0;
amt=0;
printf("\nProduct code:");
scanf("%d",&code);
i=code-1;
printf("Quantity:");
scanf("%d",&amt);
system("cls");
sum=price[i]*amt;
total=total+sum;
ipprice[j]=price[i];
strcpy(ipname[j],name[i]);
quantity[j]=amt;
ipsub[j]=sum;
printf("=============================================================\n");
for(i=0;i<lines;i++){
printf("%d:%-10s\t",i+1,name[i]);
}
    printf("\n\n%-5s%-20s%-15s%-10s%s\n",
"No.","Product","Price","Quantity","Subtotal");
printf("%-5s%-20s%-15s%-10s%s\n","===","=======","=====","========","========");
    for(k=0;k<=j;k++)
    {
        printf("%-5d%-20s%-15.2f%-10d%.2f\n",
k+1,ipname[k],ipprice[k],quantity[k],ipsub[k]);
    }
        printf("%d",j);
printf("\nPress ESC on keyboard to finalize the bill or Press any key continue...\n");
scanf(" %c", &key);
if(key!=27)
{
        j++;
    }
}while(key!=27);
        printf("%d",j);

                                    printf("\n%.2f\n",total);



return 0;
}
```

===================================================

This is how it is supposed to look like:
http://i30.photobucket.com/albums/c323/dumfuq/Screenshot37_zps81596e1a.png

The last number '11' is just me trying to monitor the j++ is going correctly.

Comment: I have more questions please help, how do i make use of self defined function in this code???